# Предусмотреть переполнения регистров SASM

Tags: ассемблер, nasm, переполнение, sasm

Есть такое задание:

> Напишите программу, которая производит расчеты по формулам
>
> ```
>  y = xx - (a + c - b), если 0<x-c<8 и 
>  y = (a-x+c)*b+1, если x-c >=8`
>  c и b - константы
> ```
>
> Предусмотрите возникающие переполнения. Значения констант и переменных, а также формулу и результат расчета выведите на экран
>
> `Предусмотрите возникающие переполнения.`

Как я понял, мне надо при возникающем переполнении выделять больше памяти под мои переменные. Как это реализовать?

Вот мой код:

```
   %include "io.inc"

   section .data

   newstr: dw "",13,10,0
   enterx: dw "Enter x:", 0
   entera: dw "Enter a:", 0
   first: dw "y = xx-(a+c-b)",13,10,0
   second: dw "y = (a-x+c)b+1", 13,10,0
   res: dw "Result: y = ",0
   exeption: dw "x-c < 0, enter x again",13,10,0
   valuex: dw "x = ", 0
   valuea: dw "a = ", 0
   valueb: dw "b = ", 0
   valuec: dw "c = ", 0

    c: db 1
    b: db 7

    x: db 0
    a: db 0
    y: db 0
    if:db 0

   section .text
   global CMAIN
   CMAIN:

   mov eax, 0


PRINT_STRING enterx
GET_DEC 1, [x] 
PRINT_STRING newstr

PRINT_STRING entera
GET_DEC 1, [a]
PRINT_STRING newstr

mov al,[x]
sub  al, [c]
mov [if], al

 CHECK:
 mov cl, 0
 ; Сравниваем х-с с нулем
 cmp [if], cl
 jl EXEPTION 
 mov cl, 8
 ; сравниваем с 8
 cmp [if], cl
 ; Если x-c < 8, то считаем по первой формуле
 jl FIRST
 ; если x-c >=
 jnl SECOND

 EXIT: 
 xor eax, eax
 ret
;---------------------------------
EXEPTION:
PRINT_STRING exeption
GET_DEC 1,[x]
jmp CHECK

FIRST:
mov al, [x]
mul al
mov bl,[a]
add bl, [c]
sub bl, [b]
sub al, bl
mov [y], al
PRINT_STRING newstr
PRINT_STRING first
PRINT_STRING newstr
PRINT_STRING valuex
PRINT_DEC 1,[x]
PRINT_STRING newstr
PRINT_STRING newstr

PRINT_STRING valuea
PRINT_DEC 1,[a]
PRINT_STRING newstr
PRINT_STRING newstr


PRINT_STRING valueb
PRINT_DEC 1,[b]
PRINT_STRING newstr
PRINT_STRING newstr


PRINT_STRING valuec
PRINT_DEC 1,[c]
PRINT_STRING newstr
PRINT_STRING newstr
PRINT_STRING res
PRINT_DEC 1,[y]
jmp EXIT
 SECOND:

mov al, [a]
sub al, [x]
add al, [c]
mov bl, [b]
mul bl
INC ax
mov [y], ax
PRINT_STRING newstr
PRINT_STRING second
PRINT_STRING newstr
PRINT_STRING valuex
PRINT_DEC 1,[x]
PRINT_STRING newstr
PRINT_STRING newstr

PRINT_STRING valuea
PRINT_DEC 1,[a]
PRINT_STRING newstr
PRINT_STRING newstr


PRINT_STRING valueb
PRINT_DEC 1,[b]
PRINT_STRING newstr
PRINT_STRING newstr


PRINT_STRING valuec
PRINT_DEC 1,[c]
PRINT_STRING newstr
PRINT_STRING newstr
PRINT_STRING res
PRINT_DEC 1,[y]
jmp EXIT
```

Comment: *Почему не зависимо от значений с и х выполняется метка SECOND?* Наверное, потому, что после завершения блока кода по метке FIRST надо бы прыгнуть куда-то нафиг, а не проваливаться в блок метки SECOND... скажем, так, как это прыгнуто в блоке метки EXCEPTION.

Comment: @Akina Ну нафиг это слишком далеко, но я вас понял, уже исправил.

Comment: Раз у вас все по байту, то достаточно под результат выделить dw и считать все в более широком регистре, загружая значения с расширением (movzbw) или считать в байтах, но использовать операции вроде adc/sbb с байтом переполнения